# How to login users safely

Tags: sql, security, session, authentication

I would simply like to ask if I'm doing the things right or if it is better if I stop before going in this direction. I have an administrative area in my website and I though to manage login using a table on my database.

When the user correctly login, I then write on a sql table the username, the session id and the IP obtained from REMOTE_ADDR server variable.

When the user ask for a private page that require to be logged in, I lookup the username on my table filtering by IP and Session ID, this return the user of the current user asking for example for "prices.aspx" page on my admin area.

I have then made my so saved records be deleted after 30 minutes. Is this safe enough? Is this a good way to expose my website to hacks? How could I improve the security?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.  Either implement `MembershipProvider` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) or use the default one for ASP .NET - I'm assuming that's what you're using.

Comment: Please show a bit of code and we'll be better able to help.

Comment: @Yuck what do you mean by default one for ASP .NET?

Comment: This sounds good in theory but still may fail in practice.

Comment: @Gumbo is REMOTE_ADDR the right server variable to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site can be hacked, it doesn't matter how your login system works.  What keeps a hacker from getting at your data?

- Encrypted Transmissions
- Never show database names, file names, passwords in front end code.
- 2 Step verification login to your website and database

The basic principles of logging a member in, or logging someone in to an authorized page are no different.

Whether you delete a record 30 minutes after it's been saved or not is totally immaterial.  If a hacker can access that data, saving it in an unsecured manner for 1 second is to long.  If you want the user session to time out after 30 minutes, just deleting the database record won't achieve that.  So, to your question, "Is it safe enough?".  No, it's not.

If your regular member login is safe, then all you need to do is have a field in your user information database, that indicates whether the user is authorized to see certain pages or not.

When your website is first loaded, don't ever load the admin pages unless it's requested, and then have the user give their password a second time.  If the user who logged in is not authorized to see an admin page, then don't even load the HTML that allows a user to request an admin page.

Comment: Hello, I'm checking databaase for IP/Session at every restricted area page call, essentially I'm doing as you say also for not loading admin page if not authorized and I have a field to tell what access level a use have. When IP and Session are not found or found with different access level than requested, the page won't load.

what do you mean with "2 Step verification login to your website and database" however?

Comment: Sounds good.  Some companies offer the option of sending you a log in verification code to your phone via text, voice call, or mobile app.  You give your password, then wait for a verification code, then enter the verification code.  So, even if a hacker guessed the right password, they can't log in without the verification code.

Comment: well in that case we no longer need a password, it would work as an internet banking pin device.